# Extract the binary value of each byte from an integer c++

Tags: c++

I want to display the binary value of each of the four bytes of an integer that is received from input. I tried to do this with bit operators but it din't work out very well. Could anyone please tell me how could i do this?

The code looks like this :

```
void main()
{
int x;
int n;

printf("Please introduce an integer number");
scanf("%d",&x);
for (n=0; n<=3; n++) {
    printf("byte %d of 0x%X is 0x%X\n",n,x,getByte(x,n));   
}
}


int getByte(int x, int n)
{
return (x >> (n << 3)) & 1;
}
```

But it returns: byte 0 is 1
                byte 1 is 0
                byte 2 is 0
                byte 3 is 0 , and that not when i inserted 8.

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: By _binary_ value, do you mean you want to see 1s and 0s?  Also, you may need to pay attention to byte order, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: The question could have different meanings as evidenced by the 3 different answers. Please show your input and expected output so we know exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Solution without using bit operators...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <math.h> 
using namespace std;

string digits[2] = {"0","1"};

// return an integer in binary format
string num2bin(int n){ return n<2 ? digits[n] : num2bin(n/2) + digits[n%2]; }

// get the b-th byte of an integer
int getByte(long n, int b){ return (long)(n/pow(256,b)) % 256; }

int main() {
    long n = 987654321; // or whatever

    // loop through the bytes in order
    for (int b=0;b<4;b++) {
        cout << "byte " << b << " = " << num2bin(getByte(n,b)) << endl;
    }
 }
```

Output:

```
byte 0 = 10110001
byte 1 = 1101000
byte 2 = 11011110
byte 3 = 111010
```

Comment: Thank you,sir!Have a lovely evening!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int i;
std::cin>>i;
std::cout<<std::bitset<8*sizeof(int)>(i);
```

Comment: `std::cout<<std::bitset<sizeof(int) * 8>(i);` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = ...;
int b0 = x&255;
int b1 = (x >> 8)&255;
int b2 = (x >> 16)&255;
int b3 = (x >> 24)&255;
```

Comment: how this does a display? and OP want binary values, what is binary value of byte?